# Swift NSAttributedString Trim

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to get ride of the white spaces in front and at the end of my NSAttributedString(Trimming it). I can't simply convert it to string and do trimming because there are images(attachments) in it.
How can i do it?

Comment: https://github.com/ovenbits/Alexandria/blob/master/Sources/NSAttributedString%2BExtensions.swift ? If you look for NSAttributedString and Trim in a Search Engine, you have some solutions, they don't work?

Comment: thank you Larme, this github project is really helpful!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create extension of `NSAttributedString` as below.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
     public func attributedStringByTrimmingCharacterSet(charSet: CharacterSet) -> NSAttributedString {
         let modifiedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        modifiedString.trimCharactersInSet(charSet: charSet)
         return NSAttributedString(attributedString: modifiedString)
     }
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
     public func trimCharactersInSet(charSet: CharacterSet) {
        var range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet as CharacterSet)

         // Trim leading characters from character set.
         while range.length != 0 && range.location == 0 {
            replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "")
            range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet)
         }

         // Trim trailing characters from character set.
        range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet, options: .backwards)
         while range.length != 0 && NSMaxRange(range) == length {
            replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "")
            range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet, options: .backwards)
         }
     }
}
```

and use in viewController where you want to use. like this

```
let attstring = NSAttributedString(string: "this is test message. Please wait.                   ")
let result = attstring.attributedStringByTrimmingCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

Answer (score 15):

**This works even with emoji in the text**

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    /** Will Trim space and new line from start and end of the text */
    public func trimWhiteSpace() -> NSAttributedString {
        let invertedSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.inverted
        let startRange = string.utf16.description.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet)
        let endRange = string.utf16.description.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet, options: .backwards)
        guard let startLocation = startRange?.upperBound, let endLocation = endRange?.lowerBound else {
            return NSAttributedString(string: string)
        }

        let location = string.utf16.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: startLocation) - 1
        let length = string.utf16.distance(from: startLocation, to: endLocation) + 2
        let range = NSRange(location: location, length: length)
        return attributedSubstring(from: range)
    }

}
```

**USAGE**

```
let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n\n     Hi  ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ buddy.              ")
let result = attributeString.trimWhiteSpace().string // Hi  ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ buddy.
```

Comment: hi, i want to remove the last image attachment from Nsattributed string. can you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: @MALIKKHABIBURREHMAN do you mean Emoji as an Image?

Comment: No, image added as NSImageAttachment to NsMutableAttrubtedString.

Comment: I found this solution breaks emoji when present at edges of the string. Issue is in range computation.

Solution below works for me: at https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-remove-extra-padding-when-converting-html-to-nsattributedstring/#remove-new-line-from-nsattributedstring.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Unicode strings are hard hahaha! The other solutions posted here are a great starting point, but they crashed for me when using non-latin strings.
Whenever using indexes or ranges in Swift Strings, we need to use `String.Index` instead of plain `Int`. Creating an `NSRange` from a `Range<String.Index>` has to be done with `NSRange(swiftRange, in: String)`.

That being said, this code builds on the other answers, but makes it unicode-proof:

```
public extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    /// Trims new lines and whitespaces off the beginning and the end of attributed strings
    func trimmedAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
        let invertedSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.inverted
        let startRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet)
        let endRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet, options: .backwards)
        guard let startLocation = startRange?.lowerBound, let endLocation = endRange?.lowerBound else {
            return NSAttributedString(string: string)
        }

        let trimmedRange = startLocation...endLocation
        return attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(trimmedRange, in: string))
    }
}
```

Comment: Love this approach. For the case where there isn't any non-whitespace characters, it should probably return an empty attributed string though.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 and above**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func trimmedAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
        let invertedSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.inverted
        let startRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet)
        let endRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet, options: .backwards)
        guard let startLocation = startRange?.upperBound, let endLocation = endRange?.lowerBound else {
            return NSAttributedString(string: string)
        }
        let location = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: startLocation) - 1
        let length = string.distance(from: startLocation, to: endLocation) + 2
        let range = NSRange(location: location, length: length)
        return attributedSubstring(from: range)
    }
}
```

**use:**

```
let string = "This is string with some space in the end.     "
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string).trimmedAttributedString()
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a swift 3 implementation, just in case anyone is interested:

```
/**
 Trim an attributed string. Can for example be used to remove all leading and trailing spaces and line breaks.
 */
public func attributedStringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(set: CharacterSet) -> NSAttributedString {
    let invertedSet = set.inverted
    let rangeFromStart = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet)
    let rangeFromEnd = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invertedSet, options: .backwards)
    if let startLocation = rangeFromStart?.upperBound, let endLocation = rangeFromEnd?.lowerBound {
        let location = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: startLocation) - 1
        let length = string.distance(from: startLocation, to: endLocation) + 2
        let newRange = NSRange(location: location, length: length)
        return self.attributedSubstring(from: newRange)
    } else {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.2 Version:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    public func trimmingCharacters(in characterSet: CharacterSet) -> NSAttributedString {
        let modifiedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        modifiedString.trimCharacters(in: characterSet)
        return NSAttributedString(attributedString: modifiedString)
    }
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    public func trimCharacters(in characterSet: CharacterSet) {
        var range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)

        // Trim leading characters from character set.
        while range.length != 0 && range.location == 0 {
            replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "")
            range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)
        }

        // Trim trailing characters from character set.
        range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet, options: .backwards)
        while range.length != 0 && NSMaxRange(range) == length {
            replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "")
            range = (string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet, options: .backwards)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Following code will work for your requirement.

```
var attString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: " this is att string")

let trimmedString = attString.string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

Comment: How exactly do i get the range?

Comment: try the code mentioned above to remove front and end space from attributed string.

Comment: Above code works fine. but it will return you `String` not `NSAttributedString`. you just have to convert `String` to `NSAttributedString` thats it. nice two line of code.

Comment: Once u convert it to string and back to attributedstring, its attributes will disappear.